# Nearby API not getting any message

Tags: android, android-ibeacon, eddystone, google-nearby

I have tried connecting to the Nearby Messages API, and have successfully been able to subscribe.

Now, my mMessageListener field is never getting callbacks for some reason. 
I have already configured my beacons using the proximity beacon api using the Android beacon service demo app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

// Declaration of member variables
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private final String TAG = "Bridge.MainActivity";
private boolean mResolvingError = false;
private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 100;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 42;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing the Google API client


}


private MessageListener mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFound(Message message) {
        // Do something with the message
        Log.i(TAG, " Found Message : " + message.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(Message message) {
        super.onLost(message);
        Log.i(TAG, " Found Message : " + message.toString());
    }
};

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "GoogleAPi Client Connected");
    foregorundSubscribeBeacons();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Api Connection Suspended : " + i);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "GoogleApi Connection failed : " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}

public void foregorundSubscribeBeacons() {
    // Subscribe to receive messages
    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to subscribe");
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                .setCallback(new SubscribeCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onExpired() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "No longer subscribing.");
                    }
                }).build();

        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, options)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Subscribed successfully.");

                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Could not subscribe.");
                            // Check whether consent was given;
                            // if not, prompt the user for consent.
                            handleUnsuccessfulNearbyResult(status);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}

private void handleUnsuccessfulNearbyResult(Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Processing error, status = " + status);
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            status.startResolutionForResult(this,
                    REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to resolve error status.", e);
        }
    } else {
        if (status.getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    "No connectivity, cannot proceed. Fix in 'Settings' and try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // To keep things simple, pop a toast for all other error messages.
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Unsuccessful: " +
                    status.getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        // User was presented with the Nearby opt-in dialog and pressed "Allow".
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Execute the pending subscription and publication tasks here.
           foregorundSubscribeBeacons();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User declined to opt-in. Reset application state here.
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to resolve error with code " + resultCode,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Initiate connection to Play Services
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    //The location permission is required on API 23+ to obtain BLE scan results
    int result = ActivityCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Ask for the location permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Tear down Play Services connection
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Un-subscribing…");

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure both the Beacon Service Demo App and the app using Nearby Messages are part of the same Google Developers Console project. You will only see messages attached by your own project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully done the beacon registration, adding the attachment to beacon on the Google Beacon Registry Server; then on subscribed successfully on device.

PRE-PREPARATION IS NECESSARY, ELSE YOU WON'T GET THE THINGS ON DEVICE.

So when beacon gets detected, the `onFound(Message msg)` gets called for each attachment of respective beacon.
THEY CLEARLY SAID, "DO SOMETHING WITH MESSAGE" in onFound(), so process your attachment only there, not the outside of onFound().

Here, if you print variable msg into Log, it should look like this :

`Message{namespace='yourprojectname-1234', type='abcd', content=[614 bytes], devices=[NearbyDevice{id=NearbyDeviceId{UNKNOWN}}]}`

Get the attachment content with `msg.getContent()` into String variable. This is normal text, and not in the base64 format.
Once you get the string content, DO WHATEVER you wanted to do.

Now it's up to you what content goes into attachment.

I have used JSON in the attachment and successfully processed for my purpose.